# Adding text to the TOP of a textbox in Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to write text in the top of an email's textbox (the cursor is at the top).

The email has a signature image inside it, hence why I'm trying to add the text to the top.

When I use "sendkey", it writes the text at the bottom, regardless of cursor position.

How do I write the text in the top?

Comment: Please post the code you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I suppose you can just send arrows keys to select a place for a text:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Arrows keys
moves = [Keys.LEFT, Keys.DOWN, Keys.RIGHT, Keys.UP]

# Send left arrow key
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('email-selector').send_keys(Keys.UP)
```